# ASP.Net updatepanel and gridview issue causing unwanted scrolling

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I have recently been trying to figure out a problem on my C# ASP.Net webforms website and finally found the cause but no fix.

**Explanation of the problem:**

I have a gridview in an updatepanel. This gridview holds images uploaded by the user and also imagebuttons. The image buttons cause a partial postback. The postback carries out an action on a selected image and refreshed the gridview.

This works great until I tested in firefox. In Firefox after the partial postback, the page scrolls up to the top of the GRIDVIEW (not the webpage).

**Cause of the problem:**

The cause of the problem was because the div that contains the gridview has no set height value in the CSS. This cause the div to shrink back to zero when the Gridview is refreshed and in turn causing the current position of scroll to be non existent (well it is but not in the div) and thus bringing the page to the top of said div.

**Fixes tried:**

- Tried setting the height of the DIV to 2000px which stopped the scroll but meant there was lots of excess space (not acceptable and this option can not be used as gridview size is dynamically changing)
- Tried JS code to move the page back to position it was before the partial postback (Also worked but the scroll moved up and the JS moved it down. This looked very unprofessional)
- Tried to setting the div to 2000px before a partial postback and then resizing it to fit it new elements in and end request... not successful.

Comment: Dummy answer but: Have you tried : `window.scrollTo = function () { }`

Comment: Don't send the height to 2000, set it according to screen resolution

Comment: setting to 2000 was a test to see if height was causing the issue. I cant set it to a screen resolution as the gridview can change size depending on how many pictures a user uploads and @VitorCanova I cannot use this as it will only scroll to an id not a postion of scroll before postback

Comment: Actually it would kill any scroll the `ScriptManager` will try. I think.